# Electricity Manipulation Variations

Tags: creative-writing, science-fiction

Trying to create a character with the ability to generate, and manipulate electricity. He's going to be an antihero. Saving people but killing the ones who inflict suffering and chaos. But I'm just wondering what are some creative ways to manipulate electricity in creative ways? Or what are some things I can learn to better understand electricity and how my character can use it in a number of different ways.

Comment: I think this question is a bit off-topic because it concerns World Building issues rather than writing itself. Maybe you can clear a bit what you want to know?

Comment: Electricity manipulation》Electromagneticity manipulation》Magneticity manipulation》Magnetic interaction is one of the four fundamental interactions *(other three is gravity, strong interaction (keeps the atom together),  weak interaction (weakly pulls the atom apart))* Congratulations, anon, you just won the superpower lottery.

Answer (score 3):

Any ways that might occur to you would also have to be expected (by the reader) to occur to your character - if you were to do a lot of reading about electrical engineering and base your ideas on that, it would look strange if your character came up with the same ideas and hadn't done similar research.

Superhero powers are usually at least part metaphoric (invisibility giving stealth or the ability to go unnoticed, flight giving the ability to rise above the mundane), so the question I would ask is what electricity means to your character. This will give ways of using electricity that fit better with the character and the story.

Comment: this isn't the answer that I'm looking for but something I still desperately needed to hear. Great feedback and I will definitely take this into great consideration thank you.